# Django + DjangoRestFramework: How to build a Django WebApp using DjangoRestFramework API?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-views

I know **Django Web App Development**,  **API Development with DjangoRestFramework**, and using **DjangoRestFramework API in other programming platforms such as JavaScript and React**.

But what I am having confusion is at using the DjangoRestFramework API in a simple Django Web Application.

How to retrieve the values that have been parsed from a serializer of DjangorestFramework API and return it to the view, which is an HTML template?

The URL `api/task-list` returns all tasks added in the database. This is how it is done in API programming.

```
def taskList(request):
tasks = Task.objects.all()
serializer = TaskSerializer(tasks, many=True)
return Response(serializer.data)
```

While in the Django web app the tasks are passed as a context and it returns or renders a template where we can loop the task from the tasklist and display it in an HTML view page.

```
def taskList(request):
tasks = Task.objects.all()
context = {'task': tasks}
return render(request, 'todo/tasklist.html', context)
```

If we have to use the API in Javascript based application than we can do it simply by doing the following:

If there is a HTML division with id list-wrapper `<div id="list-wrapper">` Than in the JavaScript section we can consume the API and do the data retrieval operation like shown below:

```
buildList()

    function buildList(){
        var wrapper = document.getElementById('list-wrapper')
        wrapper.innerHTML = ''
        var url = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/task-list'

        fetch(url)
        .then((resp) => resp.json())
        .then(function(data){
        console.log('Data:', data)

            var list = data
            for (var i in list){

            try{
                document.getElementById(`data-row-${i}`).remove()
                }catch(err){}

                var title = `<span class="title">${list[i].title}</span>`
                if (list[i].completed == true){
                    title = `<del class="title">${list[i].title}</del>`
                }


                var item = `
                    <div id="data-row-${i}" class="task-wrapper flex-wrapper">
                        <div style="flex:7">
                            <span class="title">${list[i].title}</span>
                        </div>
                        <div style="flex:1">
                            <button class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-info edit">Edit </button>
                        </div>
                        <div style="flex:1">
                            <button class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-dark delete">-</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                `
                wrapper.innerHTML += item
            }
        })
    }
```

Note: These are the code I learned while developing a TODO List app.

### Now the main confusion is

1. How to use that API developed using DjangoRestFramework in a Django Project?
2. Should I create a new django APP or can the HTML views be rendered in the same API app.
3. Will I be using the URL like I did above in JavaScript or I will be importing the classes from API project and using the methods in Django project's view method?
4. How will the project structure be? Will it be different applications inside a project or can be done in a single app?

It would be so kind if someone could help me to clear the confusion.

### Thank You in advance.

Comment: Maybe I dont get you right, then please tell me. The main difference in the views is the type of data you receive when you start a get request on an url. In DRF you normally receive json data while in a normal django project you receive a complete html css and javascript rendered page as an answer. If you dont use a frontend hosted framework like react or vue where should your javascript or html code come from that a browser needs in order to show you the tasklist as a page. Do you get my point?

Comment: I didn't clearly understand the later part of your comment after  "If you don't...". But yes I know what DRF and Django Views returns. What I wanted to learn here was how to consume the data from a API(DRF API) in a Django View such that I could display the data in a HTML template. I also know that we can return JSON RESPONSE in Django Views but I won't be using the DRF properties. That's my confusion. I hope I have kept my question clear above. Please let me know otherwise. Thanks

Comment: Ah now I got your point, I guess. You mean you have another django DRF API somewhere else and want to consume the data from that api in order to use it within your view as a context. Well I dont know if this is possible in a proper and secure way.

Comment: That's exactly what I wanted to understand . I hope I will get the answer

Comment: Your question is clearly written and understandable. I am also looking forward to solve this confusion.